# Accumulate gradients in Estimator with distribution strategy

Tags: tensorflow, distributed, tensorflow-estimator

In order to reduce the number of synchronization in distributed training, I want to do local accumulation of gradients first. it is just like you can have multiple GPUs, but in serial not in parallel.

I want to use it in the estimator.train loop with distribute strategy, such as mirrored and collective allreduce etc.

Here is my implementation, please kindly give me some inputs :)

First because I need to run different graph in the session.run(), so I modified estimator.EstimatorSpec to take more ops. Second, it seems there is no clear way to create local, none-shared variable in local GPU in the distribute strategy environment. I had to hack some variable_create_scope.

Here is hacked variable_creator function,

```
def skip_all_scope_variable_creator(next_creator=None, on_device=None, **kwargs):
  #print("skip_all_scope_variable_creator:[{}]".format(kwargs))
  initial_value = kwargs.get("initial_value", None)
  trainable = kwargs.get("trainable", None)
  collections = kwargs.get("collections", None)
  validate_shape = kwargs.get("validate_shape", True)
  caching_device = kwargs.get("caching_device", None)
  name = kwargs.get("name", None)
  variable_def = kwargs.get("variable_def", None)
  dtype = kwargs.get("dtype", None)
  expected_shape = kwargs.get("expected_shape", None)
  import_scope = kwargs.get("import_scope", None)
  constraint = kwargs.get("constraint", None)
  use_resource = kwargs.get("use_resource", None)

  with tf.device(on_device) :
    return resource_variable_ops.ResourceVariable(
      initial_value=initial_value, trainable=trainable,
      collections=collections, validate_shape=validate_shape,
      caching_device=caching_device, name=name, dtype=dtype,
      constraint=constraint, variable_def=variable_def,
      import_scope=import_scope)
```

Here is my code inside model_fn() to create three ops,

```
    loss = loss_from_model
    optimizer = some_optimizer
    tvars = tf.trainable_variables()

    gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(
      loss, tvars, colocate_gradients_with_ops=True)

    accumulate_pass_num = FLAGS.pass_per_batch

    if accumulate_pass_num > 1 :
      accum_grads = []
      accum_vars = []

      reset_grad_ops = []
      accum_grad_ops = []
      for g,v in gradients:
        accum_vars.append(v)
        if g is not None:
          with tf.variable_creator_scope(lambda next_creator=None, **kwargs: skip_all_scope_variable_creator(next_creator, g.device, **kwargs)):
            print("create accum_grad for variable:{}".format(v.name))
            tmp_grad_on_device = tf.Variable(tf.zeros_like(g), trainable=False, synchronization=tf.VariableSynchronization.ON_READ, collections=[tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES], name='tmp_accum_grad')
            reset_one_grad_op = tf.assign(tmp_grad_on_device, g, name="reset_accumulated_gradient_op")
            reset_grad_ops.append(reset_one_grad_op)
            # the return of assign_add is the value will be update
            accum_grad_on_device = tmp_grad_on_device.assign_add(g, name="accumulate_gradient")
            accum_grad_ops.append(accum_grad_on_device)
            accum_grads.append(accum_grad_on_device)
        else:
          accum_grads.append(None)

      accumulate_gradients_op = tf.group(*accum_grad_ops, name="grouped_accu_grad_op")
      reset_gradients_op = tf.group(*reset_grad_ops, name="grouped_reset_gradients_op")
      accum_grad_means = [tf.multiply(v, 1.0/accumulate_pass_num) if v is not None else None for v in accum_grads]
      accum_grads_vars = zip(accum_grad_means, accum_vars)
      minimize_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(
        accum_grads_vars, global_step=global_step, name="train")

     update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
     train_op = tf.group(minimize_op, update_ops)
     return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op, accumulate_gradients_op=accumulate_gradients_op, reset_gradients_op=reset_gradients_op, accumulate_pass_num=accumulate_pass_num)
```

Here is modified estimator.train() to run different ops,

```
      while not mon_sess.should_stop():
        if estimator_spec.accumulate_pass_num > 1 :
          # reset gradiends first
          mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.reset_gradients_op])
          for _ in range(estimator_spec.accumulate_pass_num-2):
            mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.accumulate_gradients_op])

        _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, estimator_spec.loss])
```

I tried it on the transformer model in the google's official models repository. The results were good.

My question is, are there any better ways to do it?

Should I consider use tf.cond() to select ops returned in the model_fn so Estimator and EstimatorSpec don't need to be modified? But it seems very difficult :(

Thank you very much!

Dong

Answer (score 4):

I think you can achieve this via passing train_ops to the estimator.
Calling tensorflow ops alone inside an estimator model_fn has absolutely NO effect.
Because by design the model_fn is called only once per training session, hence every op you put in it will also be executed only once. In addition to that, all tf.cond branches will be evaluated and executed during model_fn call.(you can verify this behavior by a simple conditional logging op.)
The key to achieve gradient accumulation is:

1. Wrap all your ops with tf.cond, combined with a tf.no_op as false_fn.
2. Let train_op = tf.group(*accum_ops, [conditional_minimize_op, reset_ops]), but control your execution order via control_dependencies, because tf.group does not care.
3. Pass your fully-loaded train_op to EstimatorSpec

Those ops passed to the estimator_spec or training_hooks can be executed dynamically during the training process.

Here's my code, finetuning BERT with limited GPU memory:

```
# compute batch gradient
grads = tf.gradients(loss, tvars)
(grads, _) = tf.clip_by_global_norm(grads, clip_norm=1.0)
# this is a list of sum(dy/dx) for each variable that must be paired with a tvars list.
# element may be an IndexedSlices object that does not support assignning, e.g. [g.assign(value) for g in grads]
# some of the elements are None, meaning y and x does not depend on each other.
# Nonetypes must be handled using Python, tensorflow cannot convert Nonetypes to 0.

# declare a temp variable for summation
sum_gradient = [tf.get_variable(name="sum_grads" + str(i), shape=tv.shape,
                                initializer=tf.zeros_initializer,
                                trainable=False,
                                dtype=tf.float32,
                                collections=[tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES]) for i, tv in enumerate(tvars)]
sum_ops = []
unused_variable_in_batch = []

# gradient accumulation
for i, gv in enumerate(grads):
    if gv is not None:
        sum_ops.append(sum_gradient[i].assign_add(gv, name="accumulate_gradient"))
    else:
        unused_variable_in_batch.append(sum_gradient[i])
        sum_gradient[i] = None

# NOTE : calling .assign_add does NOTHING in estimator, must wrap them all and handle them via train_ops

def apply_accumulated_gradients(sums):
    # normalize gradient
    normalize_ops = []
    for i, g in enumerate(sums):
        if g is not None:
            normalize_ops.append(sums[i].assign(tf.multiply(g, 1 / gradient_accmulation_multiplier)))
            # assign to make sure it still is a variable, or else it will become a Tensor
    with tf.control_dependencies(normalize_ops):
        minimize_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(sums, tvars), global_step=global_step)
    return tf.group(minimize_op, *normalize_ops, name="apply_accumulated_gradients")

train_op = tf.cond(tf.math.equal(global_step % gradient_accmulation_multiplier, 0),
                   lambda: apply_accumulated_gradients(sum_gradient),
                   lambda: optimizer.apply_gradients(zip([None for _ in grads], tvars), global_step=global_step))

# reset accumulation when necessary
def reset():
    counter = 0
    for i, s in enumerate(sum_gradient):
        if s is None:
            # restore reference from None to the original variable
            sum_gradient[i] = unused_variable_in_batch[counter]
            counter += 1
    return tf.group([s.assign(tf.zeros_like(s)) for s in sum_gradient])

with tf.control_dependencies([train_op]):
    reset_ops = tf.cond(tf.math.equal(do_update, 1.),
                        reset,
                        tf.no_op)
# the 2 branches must have identical structure, [op1, op2, ...] || no_op cannot be valid cond branch.
# tf.group to convert all resets into 1 op and match with no_op: tf.group() || np_op

# Increment global step
new_global_step = global_step + 1
train_op = tf.group(*sum_ops, [train_op, global_step.assign(new_global_step), reset_ops])

logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook({"accuracy": "acc"},                                                          
                                    every_n_iter=gradient_accmulation_multiplier)
output_spec = tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
                mode=mode,
                loss=loss,
                train_op=train_op,
                training_hooks=[logging_hook, accumulation_hook]  # wrap with a list
            )
```

I applied clipping on batch gradients, and simply took the average of them. This approach worked for me, but I recommend you watch your loss behavior closely on your dataset.

Also, about tf.cond(tf.math.equal(do_update, 1.),...,...), do_update is a variable managed by a Hook, it will take value 1 for every gradient_accmulation_multiplier steps, so this statement has the exact same effect as tf.math.equal(global_step % gradient_accmulation_multiplier, 0). It's just another way.

The code for the Hook is as follows:

```
class GradientAccumulationHook(session_run_hook.SessionRunHook):
    """
    Puts a certain tf.Variable to 1 once every certain steps.
    """

    def __init__(self, frequency, variable):
        self._step = 0
        self._flag = 0.
        self._freq = frequency
        self._input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
        self.assign_op = variable.assign(self._input_placeholder)

    def begin(self):
        # a hook can modify graph at begin(), after this the graph will be finalized
        self._step = tf.train.get_global_step()

    def before_run(self, run_context):
        step = run_context.session.run(self._step)  # evaluate tensor to get a step number
        self._flag = 1. if step % self._freq == 0 and step != 0 else 0.
        run_context.session.run(self.assign_op, feed_dict={self._input_placeholder: self._flag})
```

Comment: I got the following error: 'ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ' in the operation optimizer.apply_gradients(zip([None for _ in grads], tvars), global_step=global_step). Do you know by any change how I could solve it ? I am using tensorflow 1.14

Comment: @BenjaminBreton Passing no gradients in accumulation stage is intended behavior, I would suggest using your own optimizer or manually removing this assertion. You can check out the Adam weight decay optimizer in Google's BERT repository.

Comment: @FZDong does this work with MirroredStrategy or MultiHostMirroredStrategy? I get an error like this "ValueError: You must specify an aggregation method to update a MirroredVariable in Replica Context...."